# Join two unrelated tables with Criteria API

Tags: sql, join, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Suppose I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "C" (
id bigint NOT NULL,
cc integer,
CONSTRAINT "C_ID" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE "C" OWNER TO ***;

CREATE TABLE "B" (
id bigint NOT NULL,
c_id bigint references "C"(id),
bb integer,
CONSTRAINT "B_ID" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE "B" OWNER TO ***;

CREATE TABLE "A" (
id bigint NOT NULL,
c_id bigint references "C"(id),
aa integer,
CONSTRAINT "A_ID" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE "A" OWNER TO ***;
```

And I need to select rows from the table A which have common foreign keys (c_id) with rows from the table B. Though, I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT "A".aa AS "AA", "B".bb AS "BB", "C".id AS "C_ID"
FROM "A"
INNER JOIN "C" on "C".id = "A".c_id
INNER JOIN "B" on "C".id = "B".c_id;
```

In Java

```
@Entity
class A {
...
@ManyToOne
C cObj;
...
}

@Entity
class B {
..
@ManyToOne
C cObj;
..
}

@Entity
class C {
..
}
```

So question: how can I write an equivalent Criteria API Query?
Thanks.

Comment: did you find the answer for this